# Phonegap: download resources from external server and start from downloaded file

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am planning to create a responsive website using jquery/backbonejs.
my plan is to create a simple webapp to be used in phonegap (and deployed to android and iPhone via appstore/Google Play) which does only check what resources are on the server (via JSON) and download them all. after downloading them, i would like to jump to the folder having all the downloaded files and start from there.

Since iam not allowed to download files directly into my phonegap app folder, i guess i need to download the files into some kind of document folder used by the app. But the question is, is it possible to redirect from my phonegaps index.html to that other index.html in my documents folder having all the downloaded files. would it work linking to jquery.js and images being in that folder located in js/ or img/ ?

That way i could keep my app up2date, but it loads only if there is something missing or updated on the server.